# Converter Varchar para Int

Tags: sql, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso realizar uma sub consulta na Query mas os tipos de dados das colunas são diferentes . Estou utilizando a estrutura abaixo mas está com erro :

```
SELECT MIN(POPULACAO), nome_mun from cidades
select CAST(populacao AS varchar (50) ) FROM cidades
where nome_mun= ( SELECT MIN(POPULACAO) from cidades)
group by nome_mun,populacao
```

Eu preciso trazer somente o município com o menor numero de habitantes da tabela. Se alguém sugerir uma Query mais simples.

Se eu utilizar somente o `SELECT MIN(POPULACAO)`, nome_mun from cidades group by nome_mun ele trás a tabela toda . Dentro da tabela população tem o tipo Int e nome_mun varchar (50). Na verdade esse tipo de conversão no Sql me deixa um pouco confuso rs.

Answer (score 1):

Mas `nome_mun` é varchar e é o nome do município certo? Não pode se igual ao `min(populacao)`, que é numérico e não tem relação com o nome, então você precisa retornar o `nome_mun` na subquery, e calcular o min fora do `select`.

Como está usando `group by`, pode fazer isso usando `having`, assim:

```
SELECT   Cast(populacao AS VARCHAR (50) ) 
FROM     cidades 
WHERE    nome_mun= 
         ( 
                SELECT nome_mun 
                FROM   cidades) 
GROUP BY nome_mun 
HAVING   populacao = MIN(populacao))
```

Isso vai retornar o nome, onde a população seja o menor valor

Comment: Agora faz sentido.  Muito obrigado.